# am struggling to set up count in watir

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am trying to check if specific results exist on a page. There can be up to 6 sponsored results on any given page. I have tried to set to create the count so it checks until no more results are present but it only checks the first result and does not proceed to check the rest.

I have created the following

```
@continue='yes'
@count=0
until @continue=='no'
  if @b.div(:class=>'result sponsored',:index=> @count).link(:index, 0).exists?
    puts 'PASS - this advert is for a trade vehicle'
  else
    puts 'FAIL - this advert is not for a trade vehicle.'
  end
  sleep (1)
  @count+=1
  @continue='no'
end
```

Can you please advise why this only checks the first result on the page?

Apologies if being vague but am new to this. If you need me to provide more information let me know.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Note that you are setting `@continue` to `no` at the end of the loop. Therefore, the loop would only run once. If you share a link to the page or the relevant portion of the html, we could help come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = 'FAIL - this advert is not for a trade vehicle.'
@b.divs(:class=>'result sponsored').each do |div|
  if div.link.exists?
    result = 'PASS - this advert is for a trade vehicle'
    break
  end
end
puts result
```